# Is there a way to select the embedded server type with spring boot 1.x

Tags: spring-boot

I am using spring boot `1.5.15.RELEASE`.

In my `pom.xml` I have:

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
 </dependency>
```

Which as I understand by default favours the tomcat embedded server (which I'm happy with). Indeed this seems the be the case when I run the application in "production mode" I see:

> Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080

However, when running tests like this:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(properties = "spring.profiles.active=test", webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
public class EmbeddedTomcatServerTest {
...test methods
}
```

I see:

> Jetty started on port(s) 63742 (http/1.1)

A quick `mvn dependency:tree` shows:

> [INFO] +- com.github.tomakehurst:wiremock:jar:2.18.0:test
>   [INFO] |  +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-server:jar:9.4.11.v20180605:test

I am using wiremock in tests, my guess is that its presence on the test class path is coercing the spring boot auto configuration to favour Jetty instead of Tomcat in tests and the lack of the wiremock dependency on the runtime classpath reverts back to Tomcat.

I'd like both my tests and production code to use tomcat - is there a way I can ask spring to favour Tomcat even if Jetty is on the classpath.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provide your own `EmbeddedServletContainerFactory` bean. For example, to always use Tomcat, use the following bean configuration:

```
@Bean
public TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory tomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory() {
    return new TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory();
}
```